# PCA calculation using SVD vs EIG

Tags: performance, memory, machine-learning, linear-algebra, pca

PCA can be calculated using SVD and EIG, but SVD is considered more numerical stable(and seems it used more often in mature machine learning projects).

So I need some comparision of this two methods in sence of memory usage and performance and prove why one of them is more numerical stable.

I here about QR method and about Jacobi rotations method for SVD calculation, but I don't know their properties.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have all of the answers for you, but if you want to look into this, what you are asking for is a comparison of the Schur decomposition and the SVD (for example http://www.ijcaonline.org/icvci/number14/icvci1529.pdf), since I believe the Schur decomposition is the way most people compute Eigenvalues.

In my work, I generally prefer to use the singular value decomposition if for no other reason than the fact that eigenvalues can be complex numbers, whereas singular values are always real. Of course, there is a higher computational complexity with the SVD.

I have heard that the SVD is more accurate, but I admittedly do not know why. I think when people say that the SVD is more accurate, they mean that svd(A) will yield more accurate singular values than eig(A^T * A), which is definitely true. Note that A^T denotes the transpose of a matrix A.